# How to select best parameters for SVM linear kernel type

Tags: weka, svm, libsvm, text-classification

I perform a classification of two labels using libsvm. But I don't get good results for the default parameters of SVM kernel type = linear. Can any one please tell me a way to find best parameters for SVM linear kernel type

Comment: There is no standard way to do this. Maybe you need to do more data preprocessing. In general, you do not provide enough information about your data, so nobody is really able to answer your question.

Comment: I am using features extracted from Facebook :)

Comment: Grid search is a common way. I would recommend to use the RBF kernel. But stillt it has more parameter you need to vary..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `linear kernel` depends on the `C` parameter.

You could perform a `grid-search` for this parameter in order to find the 'best' matching one for your given dataset.

For weka the procedure is described [here](https://weka.wikispaces.com/Optimizing+parameters).